# Update a cte 'result' failed because it contains a derived or constant field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a cte like below;

```
;with cte as (field1, field2, field3)
```

I need to select the records from this CTE, but before I need to do some updates on one of the columns in that CTE and that update is based on a output from scalar function (it will return either 1 or 0 as output (bit)) which I use it in a case statement like below;

```
 ;with cte as (field1, field2, field3)
 update cte
 set field1 = (select 
                     case when dbo.scalarFunction (@parm1,@parm2) = 0
                        then 'New Value'
                        else cte.field1 
                     end)
 from cte
 where field2 = 'some filter' and field3 = 'some filter'

 select * from cte
```

When I execute this I get the below error;

> Update or insert of view or function 'result' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Can anyone please advice how to update my cte and then then see the updated records in cte

Comment: A CTE is not a table you can update. A CTE is an ad-hoc view, a query. `field1, field2, field3` is not a CTE. It is three names that have no meaning. Where do you get those names from? Are they supposed to be related to some table? Your UPDATE doesn't have a SET clause. So all in all, your SQL makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve actually? Do you want to update some table? Do you want to select some data? Which data? Show an example.

Comment: Can you show your `CTE` query ?

Comment: that field in CTE derived from many calculated fields from various tables lets say that cte will be the final output, but I need to update those fields CTE. and sorry set field is added in UPDATE

Comment: you want to update the based table or modify the result in CTE ? Not really quite sure what you want to do here. Perhaps you should use a temp table instead

Comment: @Squirrel, I just need to modify the result in CTE. And I have  tired it in temp table it works, but I shouldn't use tempDB in my working env (how? it is said to be hard). So I need to update those results in CTE alone

Comment: or maybe you just need another `cte` and modify the result in the second cte. something like `cte2 as (select .... from cte) select * from cte2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do this changes in select instead of update command -

```
;with cte as (field1, field2, field3)
 select
    field1 = (case when field2 = 'some filter' and field3 = 'some filter' then
                (case when dbo.scalarFunction (@parm1,@parm2) = 0
                    then 'New Value'
                    else cte.field1 
                end)
            else field1 end)
    ,field2
    ,field3
 from cte
```